# Python-Turtle: Cant interpret through files with both circles and rectangles and draw correctly

Tags: python, function, while-loop, turtle-graphics

The code below is 3 functions and a while loop to call those functions:

draw_rect(): draws a rectangle based on given parameters

draw_circle(): draws a circle based on given parameters

draw_line(): draws a line based on given parameters

All of my functions work correctly and can read text files that only have rectangles, only have lines or only have circles.

My while loop at the bottom is where I'm having trouble. I have a file with both rectangles and circles that ends up being a python logo. I can't figure out what needs to be done with this while loop to execute the right functions at the same time. Any help would be much appreciated. I have put a sample of the txt file im working with.

color blue

circle -30 0 80

circle 0 30 80

color yellow

circle 30 0 80

circle 0 -30 80

color blue

rect -84 55 60 110

rect -84 55 25 120

rect -30 80 88 82

color black

circle -20 -35 38

color yellow

circle -20 -35 32

color black

rect -58 -40 5 100

```
def draw_rect():
    smart = turtle.Turtle()
    i=0
    while i < len(file_list):

        if file_list[i] != "":

                rect = file_list[i]
                if rect[0] != 'rect':
                    return i
                else:
                    color        = str(rect[1])
                    x_coordinate = int(rect[2])
                    y_coordinate = int(rect[3])
                    width        = int(rect[4])
                    height       = int(rect[5])
                    smart.penup()
                    smart.fillcolor(color)
                    smart.begin_fill()
                    smart.goto(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
                    smart.setheading(0)
                    smart.pendown()
                    smart.forward(width)
                    smart.right(90)
                    smart.forward(height)
                    smart.right(90)
                    smart.forward(width)
                    smart.right(90)
                    smart.forward(height)
                    smart.end_fill()
                    i += 1
    return i

def draw_circle():
    smart = turtle.Turtle()
    i=0
    while i < len(file_list):
        if file_list[i] != "":
                circ = file_list[i]
                if circ[0] != 'circle':
                    return i
                else:
                    color        = str(circ[1])
                    x_coordinate = int(circ[2])
                    y_coordinate = int(circ[3])
                    radius       = int(circ[4])
                    smart.penup()
                    smart.fillcolor(color)
                    smart.begin_fill()
                    smart.goto(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
                    smart.setheading(0)
                    smart.pendown()
                    smart.circle(radius)
                    smart.end_fill()
                    i += 1
    return i

def draw_line():
    smart = turtle.Turtle()
    i=0
    while i < len(file_list):
        if file_list[i] != "":
            star = file_list[i]
            if start[0] != 'line':
                return i
            else:
                color        = str(star[1])
                x_coordinate = int(star[2])
                y_coordinate = int(star[3])
                angle        = int(star[4])
                line_length  = int(star[5])            
                smart.penup()
                smart.color(color)
                smart.goto(x_coordinate, y_coordinate)
                smart.setheading(angle)
                smart.pendown()
                smart.forward(line_length)
                i += 1
    return i

import turtle
turtle.speed(0)

file = input("What file would you like to execute?")
turtle.clearscreen()
with open(str(file),'r') as f:
    file_list = []
    for line in f:
        if line == '\n': 
            continue

        l = line.split()
        if l[0].lower() == 'color':
            color = l[1].lower()
        else:
            file_list.append([l[0].lower()] + [color] + l[1:])
print(file_list[0:])
n = 0
i = 0
while n < len(file_list):
    n = n + i
    while file_list[n] != "":
            parameter = file_list[n]
            print(parameter[0])
            if parameter[0] != 'line' or parameter[0] != 'circle':
                draw_rect()

            elif parameter[0] != 'line' or parameter[0] != 'rect':
                draw_circle()

            elif parameter[0] != 'circle' or parameter[0] != 'rect':
                draw_line()





print("Program complete")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong here:

```
        if parameter[0] != 'line' or parameter[0] != 'circle':
            draw_rect()

        elif parameter[0] != 'line' or parameter[0] != 'rect':
            draw_circle()

        elif parameter[0] != 'circle' or parameter[0] != 'rect':
            draw_line()
```

You mean `and` not `or`.  Suppose that the parameter is 'circle'.  When  the line

```
        if parameter[0] != 'line' or parameter[0] != 'circle':
            draw_rect()
```

is executed, the parameter is not equal to 'line' so `draw_rect` is executed.  The second clause is never evaluated.

This is odd code, though.  Why don't you change it to

```
        if parameter[0] =='rect':
            draw_rect()

        elif parameter[0] == 'circle':
            draw_circle()

        elif parameter[0] == 'line':
            draw_line()
```

Surely that's clearer?

EDIT: I've reorganized the code, and I think you'll agree that it's easier to understand.  It's certainly shorter.The biggest changes are

1) Pass the drawing parameters as parameters to the drawing functions, instead of keeping them in a global array.
2) Process the lines in the file with an iterator: `for line in file`  That way, you don't have to mess with indices or worry about how many line  there are.
3) Notice how I converted the entries in the lines to integers, for example `x, y, width, height = map(int, line[1:])`  Some people don't like
`map`.  They would write something like

```
x,y,width,height == [int(item) for item in line[1:]]
```

whatever floats your boat.

```
import turtle

def draw_rect(color, x, y, width, height):
     smart.penup()
     smart.fillcolor(color)
     smart.begin_fill()
     smart.goto(x, y)
     smart.setheading(0)
     smart.pendown()
     smart.forward(width)
     smart.right(90)
     smart.forward(height)
     smart.right(90)
     smart.forward(width)
     smart.right(90)
     smart.forward(height)
     smart.end_fill()

def draw_circle(color, x, y, radius):
     smart.penup()
     smart.fillcolor(color)
     smart.begin_fill()
     smart.goto(x, y)
     smart.setheading(0)
     smart.pendown()
     smart.circle(radius)
     smart.end_fill()

def draw_line(color, x, y, angle, length ):           
     smart.penup()
     smart.color(color)
     smart.goto(x, y)
     smart.setheading(angle)
     smart.pendown()
     smart.forward(line_length)

turtle.speed(0)
file = input("What file would you like to execute?")
turtle.clearscreen()
smart = turtle.Turtle()

with open(str(file),'r')  as f:
     color = 'black'    #default
     for line in f:
          line = line.strip().split()
          if  line[0] == 'color':
               color = line[1]
          elif line[0] == 'rect':
               x, y, width, height = map(int, line[1:])
               draw_rect(color, x, y, width, height)
          elif line[0] == 'circle':
               x,y, radius = map(int, line[1:])
               draw_circle(color, x, y, radius)
          elif line[0] == 'line':
               x, y, angle, length = map(int, line[1:])
               draw_line(color, x, y, angle, length)

input("Press Enter to exit")               
print("Program complete")
```

Notice that most of this is your code; I've just cleaned it up a bit.  "I'm getting better every day" is the right attitude!  Keep it up.  My experience, and the experience of programmers at large, is that the time you spend making your programs clear and readable is amply repaid by the time you save in debugging, and later maintenance.  Even with all the effort I put in at this, I can't count the times I've looked at my code six months later and thought, "What is this bit supposed to be doing?"

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually had that prior and kept getting another problem. Since changing the code back, the program now executes but gets stuck just evaluating circles.

Comment: Is the code you have posted your current code, except for the change in the `while` loop?  I'll try it out on my computer.

Comment: That problem is due to the fact that you never change `n` and `i` in your `while` loop. `n` always has the value zero.  So this is an infinite loop.  If you don't mind my saying so, the file-processing code code is badly structured and hard to follow.  That's why you made your mistake, and couldn't find it, I think. Give me a few minutes and I'll post some suggested rewrites.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it. I'm just a beginner, but am getting better every day.